# How to count the number of open workbook on a remote desktop?

Tags: vb.net, filenames, remote-desktop

I can already count the number of open excel workbook and retrieve their names on my own pc but now I want to connect to a remote pc and count it.

how and what should I do?
is it possible to do that? 
it's better if anyone can provide some code examples

thank you

I have 2 excel document opened

[image]

but in the process I only have 1 process

[image]

This is the only output I got now

[image]

btw I'm using windows7

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the executable for your program onto a shared network folder that is shared between you and the remote PC.
2. Connect to the remote PC
3. Navigate to the executable from the remote PC and run it.

Comment: but I don't want to manually run it every time on every single pc, it's not really effective and very time consuming. I was wondering if it could be run on 1 pc only to retrieve from a few pcs.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it was one computer.  You could you use: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(<computer name>) and then a for loop, like shown here: https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/113166-list-processes-running-remote-machine-how  Instead of sending to the console, you can put your results in an array and then count how many instances of Excel there are.

Comment: sorry for not stating it clearly at the first place. Thanks for the suggestion but it's not really what I wanted. No matter how many excel file you open, in the process it would only show 1 "EXCEL" instead of the document name.

Comment: You can still get the window name and/or title from each process.  For example, if you look in the task manager, I'm assuming you're looking for open excel sessions under the applications tab. Is this correct?

Comment: Try looking here to see if this will help you:  http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/get-the-list-of-running-applications-in-visual-basic.htm

Comment: thank you! but now I have another problem. When I have 2 excel book open it will only return me 1 of it.

Comment: In the processes tab in task manager, how many excel processes are listed?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. there's only 1

Comment: which versions of windows?  If there are two different workbooks open, there should be be two processes listed.  Are you able to edit your question to include a screenshot?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I'm using Windows7 for now